# 3.16 amp arc enough to melt solder

Tags: current, arc

So I was playing around and I hooked up a 19V 3.16A laptop charger to some clamps and a pencil lead...and stumbled upon carbon arc cutting. Now I'm wondering if this process can be used to solder non-sensitive connections or even weld small parts together. Thoughts?

Comment: An arc will have the temperature to fuse metals, but a shielding gas would be needed to protect liquid metal from Oxygen in the air while cooling.

Comment: Could I rig a simple co2 generator?

Comment: CO2 would be a farily ghetto arc welder for very small parts. Fun experiment but perhaps not that useful. Anyhow, your problem will be lack of constant current limiting from that power supply so it's unlikley you will ever see 3.16 A from it. A real arc welder controls the current and have high enough compliance voltage to strike an arc.

Answer (score 3):

There's still quite a technology gap between 'melting stuff' and producing good quality soldered or welded joints.

That technology is control of contamination in the joint, including, but not limited to, metal oxides. In soldering, it's done via a flux, usually cored into the solder. This operates over a fairly small range of temperatures. A wetted iron tip applied to both components with skill can usually achieve the temperatures needed. In welding, much higher temperatures are needed, don't even go there with 60 watts, and control of oxidation is far harder than with solder.